# Where to change @ipBorderColor in less ? Air Theme

Tags: less, impresspages

I am trying to understand the structure of the LEES files in the Air theme.

I wanted to change the color of the Widget Divider.

If I inspect the divider with firebug it tells me that it is line 926 in the theme.css

It is not possible to change the @ipBorderColor in  the Air Theme variables.less.

I have tried changing the color in /core/assets/ipContent/less/ipContent/variables.less (which is only place I find where I could change it) but it has no effect.

Perhaps I should not try to change anything in the core, but this does illustrate that the Less system does make it difficult to find where to change a value, using firebug is of no use as it does not tell you where the value is located in the less files.

I think I could modify the Air theme to my needs, but can I do it without using less ?

In fact can I remove the less files and only use the Air Theme css files ?

Alan

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) change variables only in your own theme. You have all the same variables in `/Theme/Air/assets/less/variables.less`. Just uncomment any of them and do the changes. They will override the variables you get from the core by default.

Changing core variables nothing happens because LESS compiler looks only into your theme's LESS files. If it finds changes, it will automatically regenerate `theme.css` file.

You can skip using LESS, too. LESS compiler automatically compiles any `*.less` file it finds in theme's `/assets/` directory. If you remove theme.less, you can work directly with theme.css without a worrying that you will loose your changes.

Keep in mind that core styles are created on purpose to make themes future compatible. Which means that if new version introduces new elements, they will be automatically styled and look good with your theme.

If changing variables is not enough, you can override styles for the widgets in the same way as you can see in `widgets.less` file. Just create appropriate selectors and you good to go.

And there are even more options how you can override the defaults. So pick one which you feel the most comfortable with. Everything works =]

Comment: Many thanks, I did not understand you could uncomment the variables in theme variables.less file and that would override the other setting - now it seems a lot more logical.